# Error in mongodb query

Tags: mongodb

I have this query

```
db.grades.aggregate([{$unwind:"$scores"}])
```

on a collection called grade that haves documents made this type

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("50b59cd75bed76f46522c364"), 
"student_id" : 3, 
"class_id" : 12, 
"scores" : [ { "type" : "exam", "score" : 95.99100704101919 }, 
             { "type" : "quiz", "score" : 70.27334558182262 }, 
             { "type" : "homework", "score" : 48.76991564672726 }, 
             { "type" : "homework", "score" : 7.832018287711584 } ] 
 }
```

When I run this query in the result the student_id field become zero in every result of the query

Comment: When I run the query, everything seems to work correctly.

Comment: I also ran this and worked correctly. I used mongo 2.6.5. What version are you using?

Comment: This query will not effect student_id field...

Comment: the last version 3.2.10

Comment: This is some results of the query with the student_id to 0 { "_id" : ObjectId("50b59cd75bed76f46522c351"), "student_id" : 0, "class_id" : 16, "scores" : { "type" : "exam", "score" : 59.1805667559299 } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("50b59cd75bed76f46522c351"), "student_id" : 0, "class_id" : 16, "scores" : { "type" : "quiz", "score" : 47.58960202938239 } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("50b59cd75bed76f46522c351"), "student_id" : 0, "class_id" : 16, "scores" : { "type" : "homework", "score" : 6.48470951607214 } }

Comment: I tried also with mongod version 2.6.12 and the student_id becomes 0. I don't know what i'm doing wrong!

Comment: Try to create a collection with the only document the one you provided and run the query. See what happens.

Comment: I tried to create a collection with the document I provided and It worked, so the query is not correct with multiple documents.